# Testing rails with rspec without requiring all initializers run?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Let's say you're working on a rails app that has a lot of initializers that call out to various external systems at startup.

When running rspec with rspec-rails it runs all the initializers, even if your test is something simple that doesn't require rails infrastructure.

I know you can use Spork to only incur this cost once but is there a way to not incur it at all? It seems silly to load up all of rails just for a simple PORO spec.

Comment: I saw the following blog post the other day, I think it may be relevant to what you're looking for: http://pivotallabs.com/spec-helper/

Comment: @H-man I think it's unrelated. Ben Lakey's interested in loading only a few initializers in `config/initializers`

Comment: True, but this may also speed things up as it'll prevent loading whole rails stack when running a simple test.

Comment: @H-man if you make this an answer instead of a comment I can give you points and possible accept it (though phiggy post basically covers it too)

Comment: what is wrong with running `rspec foo_spec.rb:11` by hand or having a shortcut mapped

Comment: @bjhaid Because that won't scale to many such tests. You aren't going to want to run them all individually.

Comment: if you want to run many test then run them all with `rspec spec whatever`, that's what we use at work and we have very massive rails apps and its not an issue, otherwise you can use `guard` which I use in my personal projects, but guard could behave funny too at times

Comment: @BenLakey Haha, that's ok. I'm too lazy. You can go ahead and accept phiggy's answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't use spork. If you want to use a preloader, look into zeus or spring.
2. You don't need to load your entire rails environment to test things that don't depend on rails. This can be as simple as explicitly requiring the dependencies you need per spec, or creating an entirely separate minimal_spec_helper for non-rails things or a rails_spec_helper for rails things.
3. Do your initializers really "call out to various external systems"? If this is what it sounds like, that your initializers are making external network/HTTP calls, that sounds like a terrible idea.